# TypeScript changed order of array after assignment

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm working with an array of objects to use it in a *ngFor*. The problem is that after the array was created with the order it must have, javascript changed the order.

The order of the array I'm working is the next when I set the breakpoint before the console.log:

[Array with the order it must have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xObR9.png)

And when I do console.log to the array, it changes the element at position 8 to position 0, and that is the order the *ngFor* takes

[Changed array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9txg.png)

The code to construct the array is the next:

```
this.recommendations.forEach(recommendation => {
        recommendation.Journeys.forEach(function (journey, indexJour) {
            journey.Segments.forEach(function (segment, indexSeg) {
                segment.Flights.forEach(function (flight, index) {
                    const newFlight: FlightAvailabityByPrice = {
                        journeyId : journey.JourneyId,
                        segmentId : segment.SegmentId,
                        company : segment.ValidatingCarrier,
                        system : segment.SourceCode,
                        flight : flight.FlightNumber,
                        departure : flight.DepartureDateTime,
                        arrival: flight.ArrivalDateTime,
                        flightNumber : flight.AircraftType,
                        stops : segment.Flights.length - 1,
                        baggage : (flight.FareOption.BaggageAllowance || '0P') + (flight.FareOption.BaggageWeight || '23K'),
                        base : flight.FareOption.FareBase + ' ' + flight.FareOption.Class,
                        cabin : flight.ClassOfServices[0].CabinType
                    };

                    if (!(journey.JourneyId in newGroup)) {
                        newGroup[journey.JourneyId] = {index: tempFlights.length};
                    }

                    tempFlights.push(newFlight);
                });
            });
        });

        const newRecommendation: RecommendationList = {
            flights : tempFlights
        };
        tempFlights = [];
        tempRecommendation.push(newRecommendation);
        tempGroups.push(newGroup);
        newGroup = {};
    });
    this.rowGroups = tempGroups;
    this.flightsInfo = tempRecommendation;
```

The html has the table component of PrimeNG for the body and it is the next

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-recoInfo let-index="rowIndex">
                            <tr class="ui-widget-header" *ngIf="rowGroups[i][recoInfo.journeyId].index === index">
                                <td colspan="14">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plane" [ngClass]="{'departure': recoInfo.journeyId === 1, 'arrival': recoInfo.journeyId !== 1}"></i>
                                    <span style="font-weight:bold">{{recoInfo.journeyId === 1 ? 'SELECT_DEPARTURE' : 'SELECT_ARRIVAL'}}</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <mz-checkbox-container>
                                        <input mz-checkbox
                                            id="select-all-{{i}}-{{index}}"
                                            type="checkbox">
                                    </mz-checkbox-container>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="assets/images/flight_companies/{{recoInfo.company}}.png" alt="{{recoInfo.company}}">
                                </td>
                                <td>{{recoInfo.system}}</td>
                                <td>{{recoInfo.flight}}</td>
                                <td>{{recoInfo.departure}}</td>
                                <td>{{recoInfo.departure}}</td>
                                <td>{{recoInfo.flightNumber}}</td>
                                <td>{{recoInfo.stops}}</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="assets/images/malas/{{recoInfo.baggage}}.png" alt="{{recoInfo.baggage}}">
                                </td>
                                <td>{{recoInfo.base}}</td>
                                <td>{{recoInfo.cabin}}</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <mz-radio-button-container>
                                        <input mz-radio-button
                                            [withGap]="true"
                                            id="flight-{{i}}-{{index}}"
                                            name="selected-{{recoInfo.journeyId === 1 ? 'departure' : 'arrival'}}-{{i}}"
                                            type="radio">
                                    </mz-radio-button-container>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-template>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the actual stripped down array examples as code, rather than screenshots, and share any relevant code you're building your array with?

Comment: I just edited the post with the code, thanks!

Comment: provide html code having ngFor

Comment: When are you doing the console.log which shows the array out of order?

Comment: I updated the post with the html. @nurdyguy I am making the console.log after the last line of code

Comment: I'm getting a similar strange beahviour and wanted to maintain the order from api w/o having to sort on ui, @JuanF did you arrive to the origin on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, when you separate all the nested loops into subroutines it makes the logic a bit easier to reason about FYI..But if just to get things done before refactoring, I would probably use a sort by that segmentId into a new array or mutate the original

```
 tempFlights.sort(function (a, b) {
 return a.segmentId - b.segmentId;
 })
```

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) where I got it from, just the actual docs

Hope this works for you and good luck!!

Comment: I used the code, but it changed all the order I need to keep, so I modified it using journeyId instead segmentId, because and again when I make the break point on the last line, it shows the array correct, but it stills showing the element at position 8 as the first

Comment: I'll update if I can catch anything else. May be helpful if you tag the question with PrimeNG as there are some different things going on in the HTML I'm not used to.

Comment: My best guess for the day is to check this line out *ngIf="rowGroups[i][recoInfo.journeyId].index === index"  You have only one condition, I have seen Angular get funny when there is no logic to catch opposite conditions. Good luck again!

Comment: I have checked the condition number of times, and it seems to be working property. All the others arrays work as expected, it just makes the change in the order for that array with that specific element. When Prime starts the for, it gets that array with the wrong order